# speed up Opencv image processing

Tags: opencv

I'm a student studying computer vision and I'm working on my project but I have a problem.  First, my project is projecting a video onto a person's clothing (it's like image mapping). We recognize the person by infrared camera and the background is white (there's nothing except for the white wall). In software, the image is converted to black and white, so the person is white and the background is black.

Below is my project's video and source code:

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNP44.jpg), [video](http://serviceapi.nmv.naver.com/flash/convertIframeTag.nhn?vid=F71502F30048E1B3643E5AA5B2AB3C43C783&outKey=V1269805a0524200df791021dc9e8493b2099898f8ae670765615021dc9e8493b2099&width=720&height=438)

```
while(1)    
{
  //grabbing infrared camera 

  ppCameras[0]->RetrieveBuffer(&cam1_img);
  cam1_img.Convert(PIXEL_FORMAT_BGR, &cam1_RGBconverted_img);

  memcpy(p_image->data,cam1_RGBconverted_img.GetData(),cam1_RGBconverted_img.GetDataSize());

  //time check 

  time1 = time2;
  time2 = timeGetTime();
  cout << "PART 1:" << time2 - time1 <<"ms"<<endl; 


  //image setting 

  contents_originMOV >> contents_originMOV_frame;

  if(firstPlay==0)
  {
    firstPlay=1;
    width = (int)contents_originMOV.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    height = (int)contents_originMOV.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    fps = (int)contents_originMOV.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); 
    count = (int)contents_originMOV.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT); 

  }

  nowFrame = (int)contents_originMOV.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);

  // setting for image repetition

  if(nowFrame >= count)
  {
    contents_originMOV.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,0);
    if(loopMode==1)
    {
      loopFirst=1;
    }
  }

  else
  {
    loopFirst=0;
  }

  //time check

  time1 = time2;
  time2 = timeGetTime();
  cout << "PART 2.1:" << time2 - time1 <<"ms"<<endl; 

  key = cvWaitKey(1);

  if(key=='q') break;

  //time check 

  time1 = time2;
  time2 = timeGetTime();

  cout << "PART 2.2:" << time2 - time1 <<"ms"<<endl; 

  //GPU time check start 
  StopWatchInterface *timer = NULL;
  sdkCreateTimer(&timer);
  sdkStartTimer(&timer);
  g_image.upload(image3);
  g_frame.upload(contents_originMOV_frame);

  gpu::cvtColor(g_image,g_grayMask,CV_BGR2GRAY); 
  gpu::threshold(g_grayMask,g_grayMask, 50, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV );
  gpu::bitwise_not(g_grayMask, g_grayMask);
  gpu::morphologyEx(g_grayMask,g_grayMask,MORPH_OPEN,element,buf1,buf2);
  gpu::morphologyEx(g_grayMask,g_grayMask,MORPH_CLOSE,element,buf1,buf2);
  gpu::cvtColor(g_grayMask,g_grayMask2,CV_GRAY2BGR);
  gpu::multiply(g_grayMask2,g_frame,g_grayMask2,1.0/255.0,-1);
  g_grayMask2.download(grayMask4);

  imshow("compose_right",grayMask4);

  //GPU time check end
  sdkStopTimer(&timer);
  float time = sdkGetTimerValue(&timer);
  cout << "GPUTime:" << time <<"ms"<<endl;
}
```

I build this code and the speed is 20~30ms (I think it's enough to follow the person's movement but it is slow). I don't know why the projector can't follow the speed of person's movement. I use visual studio 2010 64bit, opencv2.4.6 and cuda 5.5 version.

These are my questions:

1. Is there any way to speed up the projector's performance speed?
2. Is it possible to solve this problem in CUDA?

Comment: 1. what's the time *without any processing* ?'(you may be limited by one of your captures) 2. gpu:: == cuda:: (you're already trying with cuda)

Comment: better store your img on this site, your external link needs flash

Comment: Which GPU are you using?